# Block js file access from webpage source

Tags: javascript, html, security

I have some `js` files which should not be viewed by any users accessing my website i.e I don't want the contents of the `js` files to show up on the page source. The data is important so i don't want users to access at all. Is there any way i can do this ? Or is there any way to encrypt the `js` file so that I can still access the data inside, but not the users ? Or can I do some safe redirection on clicking the `js` file ?

Comment: If the JS file is being loaded and used by the client's browser, it is impossible to secure it.

Comment: The best you could do is obfuscating it to make it harder (but not impossible) to read.  Anything that is executed on the client side, such as JavaScript will always be available to the user.  You should never rely on anything on the client side to enforce security in a web app. Secrets can not be kept and rules can not be reliably enforced.  You should be minifying your JS already, some minifiers such as [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) will also optionally obfuscate the code.

Comment: you could set access control on the file which could require a pass to view it

Comment: how do i set this access control @david ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't deny access to your JS files but you may consider minifying/obfuscating your JS files to make harder for people to understand.

Check these minifier/obfuscator

- http://javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx
- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/
- http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home
- http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-online-javascript-obfuscator.htm

Comment: +1 I appreciate your techniques I used to find that coding on google and facebook page sources and I was thinking what the language they are using now I came to know these are the  techniques they use thanks

Comment: If the files contain *data* though as @Kiran said, that's pretty useless since it probably does not need any meaningful variable or function names - and object keys are not touched by javascript minifiers/obfuscators.

Comment: I have code, but inside it, i have data as well, and i need this data to be shielded. So ur telling me that even compressors wont be able to touch the data potion ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. If you think your data is too important to keep it in public access, then please consider retrieving it from server using AJAX when required.

Comment: But then people can just copy it and use http://jsbeautifier.org/ .....just saying

Answer (score 1):

Obviously that's not possible - what's available for the browser is also available to you. 
If users shouldn't be able to access data, don't send it to them but keep it on the server.

Besides that, I guess your JS is not **that** valuable anyway...

Comment: No it is. But i really can't explain in what sense here.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to block javascript file access from webpage source code and you are saying that there is some data which needs to be protected.

You can store the data at server and fetch it using AJAX call so that you no need to worry when the user checks your source code.

But still your problem is not solved because we can monitor AJAX calls and see the response. I think the only solution to your problem is to encrypt your data at server and send it to the client. Your client should be able to decrypt the data.

For encryption/decryption, most of the developers use AES and to exchange the key use [Extended Diffie Hellman Key Exchange algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange)

Users can still monitor XHR requests and see the response but the response is encrypted.

If you feel, your source code is also need to be protected then go for obfuscators.

Check this [jscrambler](https://jscrambler.com/)